# How can we write into rows and columns of an existing excel file for windows phone in a particular format ???

Tags: c#, excel

the format could be :

namestamp         count   marks   name     percentage
ddmmyyyyhhmmss       1      75     abc        75

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use a library like NPOI, however, I'm not sure on the compatibility with Windows Phone... it should work though.